# No signatures files found in META-INF. Cannot proceed. (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby, windows, calabash-android

#### Resign

D:\test>bundle exec calabash-android resign app-staging.apk

D:\test>

#### When i do run/build

```
D:\test>bundle exec calabash-android run app-staging.apk
No test server found for this combination of app and calabash version. Recreating test server.
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/) to get coloured output on Windows
WARNING: skipped META-INF/CERT.RSA as unsafe
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.6/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:188:in block (2 levels) in fingerprint_from_apk': No s re files found in META-INF. Cannot proceed. (RuntimeError) from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.6/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:170:inchdir'
from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.6/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:170:in block in fingerprint_from_apk' from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb:89:inmktmpdir'
from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.6/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:169:in fingerprint_from_apk' from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.6/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:2:incalabash_build'
from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.6/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:107:in build_test_server_if_needed' from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.6/bin/calabash-android-run.rb:16:incalabash_run'
from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.6/bin/calabash-android:86:in <top (required)>' from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/calabash-android:22:inload'
from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/calabash-android:22:in
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have `debug.keystore` file create it bu the following command, you need `keytool` which is in `JAVA_HOME/bin`:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US"
```

Then run the `calabash-android setup` to assign this debug.keystore:

```
$ calabash-android setup
  Please enter keystore information to use a custom keystore instead of the default
  Please enter keystore location
  ...
```